# Error: Reached the recursion limit while instantiating `<std::iter::Filter<std::iter::Sk...]>::{closure#0}]>::{closure#0}]>`

Tags: recursion, rust, iterator

I have a function with following declaration:

```
fn find_solutions_internal<'a, I>(&self, words: I, iterate_from: usize, chain: &mut Vec<u32>)
    where I: Iterator<Item=&'a u32> + Clone;
```

Because the function recursively iterates over the same vector (max-depth of recursion is 5) with different filters I decided that it would be more effecient to pass the iterator as an argument.

Following part of code causes error:

```
let iterator = words.skip(iterate_from).filter(|&mask| mask & last_mask == 0);
let filtered_words = iterator.clone();

iterator.enumerate().for_each(|(i, &mask)| {
    chain.push(mask);
    self.find_solutions_internal(filtered_words.clone(), i, chain); // filtered_words.clone() is what indirectly causes the error
    chain.pop();
});
```

The error:

```
error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating `<std::iter::Filter<std::iter::Sk...]>::{closure#0}]>::{closure#0}]>`
115 |         self.iter.fold(init, fold)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: `<std::iter::Filter<I, P> as Iterator>::fold` defined here
...
```

Self-contained example of the problematic code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ada8578f166ad2a34373d82cc376921f

Working example with collected iteration to vector: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c13d2d0ac17038dac61c9e2d59bbab5

Comment: Attempted to reproduce the error with just a code in question, stubbing out any undefined part, - no luck: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=48d12857014cf7522ea00e55fa2e74e2 Could you create a self-contained example?

Comment: The provided code is part of the recursive function. I have added permalink to self-contained example to the question.

Comment: `last_mask` never changes, and `x & 0` is always zero.

Comment: Yeah, because it is not my whole code. It is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: As you can see in the first example, error occurs even though the total number of recursive calls is finite (as demonstrated in the second example with vectors).

Comment: The problem is that the compiler can't determine statically that the recursion is finite (I'm not sure it even tries), but since `find_solutions_internal` is generic it takes a different type for each recursion level, meaning the compiler is trying to create an infinite number of instances of this function. The standard solution would be to remove the generic and use `&mut dyn Iterator<Item=&'a u32>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jmb commented, the compiler does not try figuring out how many times the function recurses, at least not for the purpose of allowing this kind of code to compile. The compiler assumes each call to `find_solutions_internal()` can potentially recurse, and so the compiler gets stuck repeatedly instantiating the function, as each recursive call has a unique iterator parameter type.

We can fix this problem by passing the iterator as a trait object when making the recursive call, though the fact that we're cloning the iterator complicates things, as the `Clone` trait doesn't work with trait objects. We can work around that with the [`dyn_clone`](https://docs.rs/dyn-clone/latest/dyn_clone/index.html) crate, at the cost of some boilerplate.

First we define a clonable iterator trait:

```rust
use dyn_clone::DynClone;

trait ClonableIterator<T>: Iterator<Item = T> + DynClone {}
impl<I, T> ClonableIterator<T> for I where I: Iterator<Item = T> + DynClone {}
dyn_clone::clone_trait_object!(<T> ClonableIterator<T>);
```

Then in the recursive call we construct the trait object:

```rust
self.find_solutions_internal(
    Box::new(filtered_words.clone()) as Box<dyn ClonableIterator<_>>,
    i,
    chain,
);
```

---

While the above solution works, I think it'll likely end up slower than doing the simple thing of just collecting into a `Vec`. If the vector is really big, using a datastructure like `Vector` from the [`im`](https://docs.rs/im/latest/im/index.html) crate, which supports O(1) cloning and O(log n) remove might be faster.